# How to use only "PayPal" button from ngx-paypal module?

Tags: angular, user-interface, paypal, customization

I'm using ngx-paypal module in Angular11 project.
I want to remove "Pay Later" button and "Two easy ways to pay" label, and want to display only "PayPal" button.
How to configure the modules for this purpose?

[image]

My current configuration is as following.

```
this.payPalConfig = {
      currency: 'USD',
      clientId: environment.paypalKey,
      advanced: {
        commit: 'true'
      },
      style: {
        label: 'paypal',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        size: 'small',
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'silver',
      },
      createOrderOnClient: (data) => <ICreateOrderRequest>{},
      onApprove: (data, actions) => {},
      onClientAuthorization: (data) => {}
      onCancel: (data, actions) => {},
      onError: err => {},
      onClick: (data, actions) => {},
    };
```

html code is simply ngx-paypal tag.

```
<ngx-paypal [config]="payPalConfig"></ngx-paypal>
```

Comment: I suggest you to checkout the documentation, i couldn't find any property of `IPayPalConfig` to hide the button  :( but I hope it helps: https://enngage.github.io/ngx-paypal/

Comment: I checked but not sure how to hide unnecessary buttons and labels.

Comment: Where is HTML code ?

Comment: html code is simply ngx-paypal tag.

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to notice that if you specify a style of `horizontal` instead of `vertical` in the configuration, it removes the second button.

Not sure if this will help in all cases, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

```
style: {
    label: 'paypal',
    layout: 'horizontal'
}
```

Horizontal:

[image: horizontal]

Vertical:

[image: vertical]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my current setting is "horizontal".

Comment: bummer! :-). I wonder if there are settings that can be controlled on the PayPal side.  I'm not familar, but I'd imagine there is some sort of Developer Dashboard where you create an API key.  I wonder if there are settings in there that would control which options are available when your api key is used.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'll check agian paypal side.

Answer (score 0):

If you land here in 2023, you can disable the button text with the `tagline` attribute, like so:

```
    style: {
        tagline: false,
        layout: 'horizontal'
    }
```

here's the official PayPal documentation for button configuration: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/standard/customize/buttons-style-guide/

`tagline: true` is not compatible with the vertical layout.